# Are the "avatar" images broken?

Tags: bug

Is something wrong with the display of avatar images? See below. Chrome 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10. Same thing on the main site.

[image: Screenshot of broken images on meta.]
[image: Screenshot of broken images on main site.]

Comment: Cannot replicate - same setup

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `www.gravatar.com` is blocked by the corporate firewall (McAfee Web Gateway) as a "Malicious Site". Found: [Is Gravatar a privacy risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk).